# Images captured from my Android app are saved, but not displayed on the gallery app

Tags: android, android-camera, android-sdcard, android-image

I have build an Android application which capture images and save in the /mnt/sdcard/Pictures/MyFolder Actually application is running perfectly and also images store in the given path. The problem is I cannot see the images till I restart the device. Can I handle the situation in my coding?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by "see the images"?  Do you mean in the gallery app?

Comment: I meant, when I open the Gallery I can't see the captured images. But after I restart the device I can see those images.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If what you mean is that you cannot see the images in your gallery app you can use this to fix it:

```
String[] paths = { "/mnt/sdcard/Pictures/MyFolder" };
String[] mediaType = {"image/jpeg"};
MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(this, paths, mediaType, null);
```

Comment: this works fine. Thanks. But I got an issue. In my application I capture series of images. But finally show only the second image after the scan completed. Can you please tell me what could be the problem.

Comment: are all the images saved as jpeg? or are there any png?